# Can you give a method an attribute created by another method in the same class in pygame?

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have some code where I am trying to animate a sprite. However, I need to use an attribute (direction) defined in a method (walk) in my method (animate). Is this possible?

```
class character():
```

init and animate are here

```
    def walk(self, x, y, direction):
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if (event.key == K_LEFT):
                self.x-=1
                self.direction = 2
                print(self.direction)

            elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
                self.x+=1
                self.direction = 3

            elif (event.key == K_UP):
                self.y-=1
                self.direction = 0

            elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
               self.y+=1
               self.direction = 1



Character.animate(direction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

You can initialise the attribute in `__init__`,

change it in `walk`,

and call it using `Character.animate(Character.direction)`

an example:

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self):
        self.direction = 0

    def walk(self, x, y, direction):
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if (event.key == K_LEFT):
                self.x-=1
                self.direction = 2
                print(self.direction)

            elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
                self.x+=1
                self.direction = 3

            elif (event.key == K_UP):
                self.y-=1
                self.direction = 0

            elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
               self.y+=1
               self.direction = 1
     def animate(self, driection):
         print direction

#### Create the character object ####
bob = Character()


####  Call the animate function  ####
bob.animate(bob.direction)
```

Also if the direction will always be the attribute of the same object (bob),
you don't have to pass the direction in because the function has inherant access to it:

```
 def animate(self):
     print self.direction

 bob.animate()
```

All this may seem confusing so ask away if you need any clarification.

Hope this helps.